# Evenly distribute decor elements on a wall

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some small program which will help me to calculate how many decor elements I need on the wall, and and what will be the distance between elements.

Let's say **wall = 128.3 cm** in width and element is **panel = 4.3 cm** in width

I need some formula which will help me to calculate the gap between elements ( panel ) so, that I don't have to cut elements in width.

Also please refer to attached image.

[image: figure of a sample distribution]

Here is my code so far:

```
wall_length = float(128.3)
panel_width = float(4.3)
print('\n','\n','\n','\n')

num1 = (float(wall_length) / float(panel_width))
num2 = num1 / 2
num3 = num2 + 1
num4 = num3 * float(panel_width)
num5 = wall_length - num4
num6 = num5 / num2
num7 = num6 + panel_width

print('###########################', '\n', 'num1 - result! Divide wall with Panel', '\n', '=', num1, '\n') 
print('###########################', '\n', 'num2 - result!', '\n', num1, '/', '2', '=', num2, '\n')
print('###########################', '\n', 'num3 - result!', '\n', num2, '+', '1', '=', num3, '\n')
print('###########################', '\n', 'num4 - result!', '\n', num3, '*', panel_width, '=', num4, '\n')
print('###########################', '\n', 'num5 - result!', '\n', wall_length, '-', num4, '=', num5, '\n')
print('###########################', '\n', 'num6 - result!', '\n', num5, '/', num2, '=', num6, '\n')
print('\n', '\n', '\n','\n', '\n', '\n')

print('###########################','\n','YOUR GAP SIZE IS','\n',num6,'\n' )
print('###########################','\n','YOUR PANEL SIZE + GAP SIZE','\n',num7,'\n')
print('###########################')
print('\n', '\n', '\n','\n', '\n', '\n')
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question completely. You can use 3 panels width equal gaps, also you can use 10 panels with equal gaps. There is an upper limit here, and it is `int(wall_length / panel_width).`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, gap between elements must be close as possible to element width 4.3 cm.

Comment: Ok. Should the wall start and end with a panel? I mean, is "10 panels and 10 gaps" scenario possible? Or, should it be "10 panels and 9 gaps"?

Comment: Yes, wall shoul always start and end with panel in full width. 
Doesn’t matter, most important thing is that between panels is always a gap, which is close as possible in size of element it self. 
As the length of wall can change, so the quantity of elements and size of gaps may vary.

Comment: It does matter actually, The total number of gaps and panels cannot be even (`num1 ` in your code) since the wall should start and end with a panel.

Answer (score 1):

First, I need to say a few things:

1. You don't need to use `wall_length = float(128.3)`. `wall_length = 128.3` will do the same.
2. The total number of gaps and panels cannot be even (`num1` in your code) since the wall should start and end with a panel.
3. You can try different alternatives for that total number, and choose the minimum difference between panel width and gap width. For example, `128.3 / 43 = 29.837` and you can try 29, 31 to see which one is the best.

Here is a method:

```
def print_possible_gap_widths(wall_length, panel_width):
    num_total = wall_length // panel_width 

    # num_total cannot be even since the wall should start and end with a panel
    if num_total % 2 == 0:
        num_total += 1

    for total in [num_total - 2, num_total, num_total + 2]:
        num_gaps = total // 2
        num_panels = total - num_gaps
        total_gap_lengths = wall_length - (num_panels * panel_width)
        gap_width = total_gap_lengths / num_gaps
        print("Gap width:", gap_width,  "Diff:", abs(panel_width - gap_width))
```

For `128.3` and `4.3`, call `print_possible_gap_widths(128.3, 4.3)`, and the result will be:

```
Gap width: 5.23846153846154 Diff: 0.9384615384615405
Gap width: 4.557142857142858 Diff: 0.257142857142858
Gap width: 3.9666666666666677 Diff: 0.33333333333333215
```

So, the best one is `4.557142857142858`.

For `128.3` and `8.9`, call `print_possible_gap_widths(128.3, 8.9)`, and the result will be:

```
Gap width: 11.0 Diff: 2.0999999999999996
Gap width: 8.157142857142858 Diff: 0.742857142857142
Gap width: 6.025 Diff: 2.875
```

So, the best one is `8.157142857142858`.

At the end, you can compare the results and decide.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe another solution to get the gap width which is almost the same as panel width.

```
def get_panel_number(wall_length: float, panel_width: float) -> int:
    """
    1. Substract width of the first pannel to get wall length to
    distribute rest of panels
    2. Divide the output of above substraction by the width of panel to get 
    maximum
    number of panels and the fraction of the last panel
    3. Divide that number by 2 and get integer of it to get number of panels
    4. Add the first panel to that output to get overall number of panels
    """
    wall_length_to_distribute = wall_length - panel_width
    maximum_number_of_panels = wall_length_to_distribute / panel_width
    return int(maximum_number_of_panels/2) + 1

def get_gap_width(
    wall_length: float, panel_width: float, number_of_panels: int
) -> float:
    """
    1. From wall_length substract number of panels multiply by panel width to 
       get how many gaps in total you have
    2. Substract 1 from number of panels to get number of gaps
    3. Divide gaps width in total by number of spaces to get one gap width

    """
    gaps_width_in_total = wall_length - (number_of_panels * panel_width)
    number_of_gaps = number_of_panels - 1
    return gaps_width_in_total / number_of_gaps



wall_length = 128.3
panel_width = 4.3


number_of_panels = get_panel_number(wall_length, panel_width)
gap_width = get_gap_width(wall_length, panel_width, number_of_panels)

print(f"Wall length: {wall_length}")
print(f"Panel width: {panel_width}")
print(f"Number of panels: {number_of_panels}")
print(f"Gap between panels: {gap_width}")
```

Output:

```
Wall length: 128.3
Panel width: 4.3
Number of panels: 15
Gap between panels: 4.557142857142858
```

Which version of python you use? That program needs at least 3.6 because of `f-string`